# Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection client trial install

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

I need to test some software on a PC that has Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection installed, but I don't have a set of IT professionals and servers at my immediate disposal. Microsoft does offer a trial; is it possible to install and run it just on one PC without a server installation?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: Unfortunately the "try it" part isn't quite that simple.

Comment: To explain: I didn't find a direct installer for Microsoft FEP online; all I could find were installers for System Center, none of which seemed to be client-side installers, and none of which clearly presented FEP. But I did find the FEP installer hidden within one of the System Center download packages, as explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft says that the client program may be installed without the server, if it is installed from a command prompt: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff823900.aspx. I didn't find the exe that it said to run ("FEPInstall.exe"); but I did find an installer that worked fine, even without the command prompt.

From https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/evalcenter/evaluate-system-center-configuration-manager-and-endpoint-protection, download SC_Configmgr_1511.exe. Run it to extract the contents. Then run SC_Configmgr_1511\SMSSETUP\CLIENT\SCEPInstall.exe to install Forefront Endpoint Protection.